# hide() show() without delay on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, show-hide

I have next problem, in my code i need to hide one div and show next one immediately without delay. I use next code:

```
$('.first').hide();
$('.second').show();
```

On desktop or Andorid mobile devices it works good, but on iOS mobile devices, for example on Iphone X it works with flashing, i mean that first i see how first element disappears and then second appears like it is a small delay between two functions. I also tried to write functions like

```
$('.first').hide(0);
$('.second').show(0);
```

or even

```
$('.first').hide(0, function(){
$('.second').show();
});
```

but nothing. So could anybody give me any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try with vanilla JS? something like `document.querySelector('.first').style.display = 'none'`?

Comment: @NirTzezana No, i didn't, but at the moment i want to understand where is problem with this jquery code, why it works ok on android or desktop devices but has a problems with iOS. By the way i tried it in Safari and Chrome on Iphone, so it is not a browser issue

Answer (score 0):

So i find a solution. Looks that problems was in hide()/show() functions. I have replaced them with .css('display', 'none') and .css('display', 'block') functions and animation works without flashing